# Combining pagination and non query grouping in Slick 3.0

Tags: scala, database, pagination

I have the following tables:

```
val postTable = TableQuery[Posts]
val postTagTable = TableQuery[PostTags]
val tagTable = TableQuery[Tags]
```

One post can have multiple tags and `postTagTable` just contains the relation.

Now I could query the posts and tags like this:

```
val query = for {
    post <- postTable
    postTag <- postTagTable if post.id === postTag.postId
    tag <- tagTable if postTag.tagId === tag.id
} yield (post, tag)

val postTags = db.run(query.result).map {
    case result: Seq[(Post,Tag)] => 
        result.groupBy(_._1).map {
            case (post, postTagSeq) => (post, postTagSeq.map(_._2))
        }
}
```

Which would give me a `Future[Seq[(Post, Seq(Tag))]]`. So far so good.

But what if I want to add pagination for the posts? Since one Post can have multiple Tags with the above query, I don't know how many rows to take from the query, in order to get, let's say, 10 Posts.

Does anyone know a good way of getting the same result with a specific number of Posts in a single query?

I am actually not even sure how I would approach this in native SQL without nested queries, so if someone has a suggestion in that direction I would also be glad to hear it.

The kind of query I am currently doing:

```
val pageQuery = postTable drop(page * pageSize) take(pageSize)

val query = for {
    pagePost <- pageQuery
    post <- postTable if pagePost.id === post.id
    postTag <- postTagTable if post.id === postTag.postId
    tag <- tagTable if postTag.tagId === tag.id
} yield (post, tag)

val postTags = db.run(query.result).map {
    case result: Seq[(Post,Tag)] => 
        result.groupBy(_._1).map {
            case (post, postTagSeq) => (post, postTagSeq.map(_._2))
        }
}
```

But this obviously results in a nested query. And this is what I would like to avoid.

Another 2-query solution that would be possible:

```
val pageQuery = postTable drop(page * pageSize) map(_.id) take(pageSize)

db.run(pageQuery.result) flatMap {
    case ids: Seq[Int] => 
        val query = for {
            post <- postTable if post.id inSetBind ids
            postTag <- postTagTable if post.id === postTag.postId
            tag <- tagTable if postTag.tagId === tag.id
        } yield (post, tag)

        val postTags = db.run(query.result).map {
                case result: Seq[(Post,Tag)] => 
                     result.groupBy(_._1).map {
                         case (post, postTagSeq) => (post, postTagSeq.map(_._2))
                     }
        }
}
```

But this would take two trips to the database and uses the in operator, so it's probably not as good as the join query.

Any suggestions?

This is my actual production code as requested:

```
def pageRatings(teacherId: Long, page: Int, pageSize: Int = 10): Future[Page[(Rating,Option[Comment],Option[Course],Seq[RTag])]] = {
    val offset = pageSize * page
    //Query to get the total count of ratings
    val countQuery = table.filter(_.teacherId === teacherId)
    //Query to join with, to get only the requested page of ratings
    val joinQuery = countQuery.drop(offset).take(pageSize)

    //Get total row count to calculate max page
    val totalRows = countGeneric(countQuery)

    //Get all possible info to one rating (all three values are optional, all but tagTable are 1:1)
    val query = joinQuery
                  .joinLeft(commentTable).on(_.commentId === _.id)
                  .joinLeft(courseTable).on(_._1.courseId === _.id)
                  .joinLeft(tagTable).on(_._1._1.id === _._2.ratingId)

    //Flatten the result structure and sort
    val normalized = (for {
      (((rating, comment), course), rTag) <- query
    } yield (rating, comment, course, rTag.map(_._1))).sortBy(_._1.createdAt.desc)

    val result = db.run(normalized.result)


    result.flatMap({result =>
      //group the result to get a list of rtags for each rating, comment, course combination
      val grouped = result.groupBy {
        case (rating, comment, course, rtag) => (rating, comment, course)
      } map {
        case ((rating, comment, course), seq) => (rating, comment, course, seq.map(_._4).flatten)
      } toSeq

      //Calculate max page
      totalRows.map { rows =>
        val pages = rows % pageSize match {
          case 0 => rows % pageSize
          case _ => rows % pageSize + 1
        }
        Page(grouped, page, offset, pages, pageSize)
      }
    })
  }
```

Can I somehow bypass the nested query (`joinQuery`) and go with a single select statement?

Comment: I already posted this question on stackoverflow, but on second thought, since I already have working solutions and I am only looking for better alternatives, I figured code review would be better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016938/whats-a-good-way-to-combine-pagination-and-non-query-grouping-in-slick-3-0

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Hypothetical language like "Let's say we have…" can be problematic; unlike Stack Overflow, we prefer to see real code in its native habitat. If you want to ask a question with simplified code, please change it to "I have…", and just roll with it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, added my actual code to the question.